# Alamofire upload progress, total expected bytes doubles itself

Tags: json, swift, upload, alamofire, progress

I'm trying to upload JSON data using Swift Alamofire, my swift code is showing as below:

```
    var billString = Mapper().toJSON(bill!)

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: String(NSString(format: "%@bill/add", BASEURL))
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let data: NSData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(billString, options: [])

    manager.upload(request, data: data)
        .authenticate(user: user, password: password)
        .progress({ (written, totalWritten, expectedWritten) -> Void in
            onProgress(totalWritten, expectedWritten)
        })
        .responseObject { (response: Response<BillWrapper, NSError>) -> Void in }
```

bill includes some strings, date, and an image data.The uploading process works just fine, it would always upload the whole bill successfully, but the progress doesn't seem so. The first time when totalWritten reaches expectedWritten, expectedWritten will double itself, and the progress will go on until the second time totalWritten reaches expectedWritten before it stops. Anyone has any idea about what could lead this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Did you find a reason of it ?

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot about this, but if I can recall correctly, I did something wrong uploading files there, it doesn't have anything wrong with Alamorefire or progress call.